# Annotate coordinates in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinates

everyone!
Does anybody know how to set up coordinates for annotate in ggplot?
By default x, y defines center of text string. I need define start point? Generally i'm trying to avoid this:[image]

Thanks

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36129904/2461552) may be related to what you are trying to do.  If not, adding a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) will make it clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks, Aosmith! it's exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make geom\_text plot within the canvas's bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241182/how-to-make-geom-text-plot-within-the-canvass-bounds)