# ggplot2 data labels outside margins

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making many figures in ggplot2 using a for loop, but my data labels are extending beyond the plot margin. I've tried using expand, but it only works for some figures. When I try to use `par(mar)` I get this error message:

> Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot.

I also tried just using `ggsave` to save as a really wide file, but 1) that looks odd and 2) that won't work for making so many different figures.

Does anyone know of any other workarounds? Ideally a way to have the inner plot margins automatically set per figure based on the length of the bars + data labels. Below is the code I'm using and an example figure (you can see the bar for 'x' is outside the margin). Thank you in advance!

```
for (i in each) {
  temp_plot = ggplot(data= subset(Data, Each == i)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
             aes(x = reorder(Letter, +Number), y = Number, fill = factor(Category))) + 
    xlab("Letters") + 
    ggtitle(paste0("Title"), subtitle = "Subtitle") + 
    coord_flip() + 
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=16), 
          plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00358E", "#00AFD7"), 
                      name= "Category", 
                      labels=c("This","That")) +
    geom_text(family="Verdana", size=3, 
              aes(label=Number2, x=reorder(Letter, +Number), y=Number), 
              position=position_dodge(width=0.8), hjust=-0.001) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma, expand = c(0.01,0)) + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = letters)
  ggsave(temp_plot, file=paste0("Example", i,".jpeg"))
}
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: My general idiom for this is to explicitly set `limits=c(0,b)` for `scale_y_continuous()` and ensure `b` is an a % out from that. Said % is something you'll need to figure out as we all have aesthetic preferences. If it's a one-off plot I just hardcode a # but if it's a series of similar ones (like this) I use that % computation method.

Comment: You can add `clip = off` inside `coord_flip()` similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50202854/786542)

Comment: It's hard to say without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I'm not sure what exactly is going on with your `expand` argument in your y scale, but it looks like you're setting very very small padding or no padding around the range of your data. Look at the docs for `scale_*_continuous` and try out using `expand_scale`

Comment: I don't think you can change the plot margins automatically to take into account the length of the text label in this example, because stretching & compressing the plot would affect the amount of buffer required, in x-axis terms. Perhaps you can orient the label inwards instead? Check out the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241182/how-to-make-geom-text-plot-within-the-canvass-bounds) for a discussion. In your case, that would be something like `hjust = "inward"` for `geom_text()`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a simple solution: `+ ylim(0, 130000)`

Answer (score 1):

scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)) )