# Force facet_grid to plot facets in the same order as they appear in the data set

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am working on visual representations of single case studies. I need to make some changes to my graph in ggplot2, but I found this to be a bit challenging. Here is a brief description of the variables contained in the toy data set that I used to make a reproducible example:

- Occasion: Number of the session rater evaluated the behavior (from 1 to n);
- Time: Number of each condition (baseline from 1 to n and intervention from 1 to n);
- Phase: Condition (A = baseline or B = intervention);
- ID: student code in the study
- outcome: total score on a behavioral checklist.

The cases are ordered based on a criterion (i.e., the first intervention session) in the data set. Unfortunately, when I created different facets with `ggplot2::facet_grid`, the cases are sorted by their number and I got what you can see in the image below. I tried to change the variable type (from integer to factor, from factor to character, etc.), but nothing seemed to change. Finally, I can't order the facets manually because the real data set consists of several more cases.

```
outcome <- c(4, 8, 10, NA, 15, 7, 7, 9, 14, NA, 16, 4, 3, 2, 2, 7, 7, 9, 14, NA, 3, 6, 6, NA, 5, 9, 11, NA, 6, 3, 4, 8, 7, NA, NA, 3)
Phase <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
Time <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Occasion <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)


db <- data.frame(ID, Occasion, Time, Phase, outcome)

intervention_lines <- db %>% 
  filter(Phase == "A") %>% 
  group_by(ID, Phase) %>%
  summarise(y = max(Occasion)) 

db %>% na.omit(outcome) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Occasion, y = outcome, group = Phase)) + 
  geom_point(size = 1.8) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.65) +
  facet_grid(ID ~ .) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "y", breaks = seq(0, 11, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "x", limits = c(0, 30)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank()) +
  annotate("segment", x = -Inf, xend = Inf, y = -Inf, yend = -Inf) +
  geom_vline(data = intervention_lines, aes(xintercept = y + 0.5), colour = "black", linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: Whenever I hear somebody ask *"how to order ..."* when using `ggplot2`, the answer has always returned back to `factor(..., levels=c(...))`. The key is that `factor(x)` does not preserve the order in the data (see `levels(factor(c('a','c','b')))`), so you must explicitly provide the order with either `factor(.., levels=...)` or `levels(fctr) <- c(...)`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what order you'd like and how to get that from the data alone?

Comment: @JonSpring you can get the information from the object `intervention_lines` and rearranging from the smallest to the biggest value; however, to keep my example easy, I ordered the cases in such a way from the beginning. So in this case, the order would be 1, 7, 2 and 3

Comment: @r2evans thanks for your answer! Do you happen to know a way to use the method you suggested without needing to specify the name? Maybe creating an object with the unique values of the cases? I tried to use this `mutate_at(vars(ID), funs(factor(., levels = unique(.)))) %>% ` before plotting the graph, but it doesn't change anything. Maybe I am missing something in that line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into some trouble since your plot is using two data frames for different layers, and they need matching factors for the facet ordering to work.

I did that by converting ID to a factor and then ordering it by `intervention_lines$y` in both places.

```
library(forcats)
intervention_lines <- db %>% 
  filter(Phase == "A") %>% 
  group_by(ID, Phase) %>%
  summarise(y = max(Occasion)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(ID = ID %>% as_factor() %>% fct_reorder(y))

db %>% na.omit(outcome) %>% 
  mutate(ID = as_factor(ID)) %>%
  left_join(intervention_lines %>% select(ID, y)) %>%
  mutate(ID = ID %>% fct_reorder(y)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Occasion, y = outcome, group = Phase)) + 
  geom_point(size = 1.8) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.65) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "y", breaks = seq(0, 11, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "x", limits = c(0, 30)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank()) +
  annotate("segment", x = -Inf, xend = Inf, y = -Inf, yend = -Inf) +
  geom_vline(data = intervention_lines, aes(xintercept = y + 0.5), colour = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
  facet_grid(ID~.)
```

[image]