# Avoid cut geom_label() with facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, annotate

in the plot below I have data distributed into four groups separated via `facet_wrap()`. However, these groups have an uneven distribution of the data, hence, all groups have different bar sizes.

**How can I avoid cut the geom_label() of groups one and two** ?

[image: img]

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

###

cor12 <- brewer.pal(12, "Paired")
cor5 <- brewer.pal(7, "Pastel1")

myColors <- c(cor12, cor5)
names(myColors) <- c('Não oferta',
                     '1h - 3h',
                     '4h - 5h',
                     '6h - 8h',
                     '9h - 10h',
                     'Mais de 10h', 'Mais de 15h',
                     '20h', 'Mais de 20h', 'Mais de 30h',
                     '50% em LA', '100% em LA')

### plot:

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = prop, x = fct_rev(CH), fill = CH, pattern = Q9)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = myColors, name = NULL) +
  geom_label(aes(label = str_glue('{round(prop, 1.5)}%')),
             nudge_y = 15, #15
             nudge_x = 0.3, #0.05
             colour = 'black',
             fill = "yellow",
             label.padding = unit(0.125, "lines"),
             size = 3.5) + 
  
  ### FLIP IT:
  
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  facet_wrap(~Q9, scales = "free_y") +
  
  
  ### SHOW N
  
  geom_label(aes(label= str_glue('n = {n}')),
             size = 2,
             nudge_x = 0.3,
             nudge_y = 30,
             fontface = "italic",
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  
  ### SHOW % IN THE X-AXIS:
  
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100),
                     labels=scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
  
  ### LABELS: 
  
  labs(x = "times",
       y = '%',
       title = "a title") +
  
  ### THEME:
  cowplot::theme_half_open() +
  theme( 
    
    text = element_text(family = "sans",
                        size = 14,
                        hjust = 0.5),
    
    #plot.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0),
    
    
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.justification = "center",
    legend.background = element_rect(color = "black"),  #bloco com legendas
    legend.margin = margin(t = 5, r = 5, b = 3, l = 3),
    
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12), 
    
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                               size = 12), # legenda de baixo
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13.5,
                                face = "bold",
                                margin = margin(t = 20, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13.5,
                                face = "bold"),
    
    ### Facets: 
    
    strip.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",
                                family = "sans",
                                size = 18,
                                colour = 'green'),
    strip.background = element_rect(size = 3,
                                    fill = 'yellow'),
    strip.switch.pad.grid = unit('10', "cm"),
    
    strip.clip = "off")
```

#### QUESTIONS:

*1:* How can I avoid cut the `geom_label()` of groups one and two ?

**Bonus** : is there a way to dynamically set `geom_label()` so that the labels always get stuck to a certain position according to each bar size? (hence, I don't have to set them manually and groups with different amount of data get the labels at the same place) ?

##### Edits:

I need a solution to achieve this:

[image: d]
[image: ds]

#### Data:

```
structure(list(CH = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Não oferta", "1h - 3h", "4h - 5h", "6h - 8h", 
"9h - 10h", "Mais de 10h", "50% em LA"), class = "factor"), Q9 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("one", "two", 
"three", "four"), class = "factor"), n = c(1L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), prop = c(100, 92.31, 7.69, 44.44, 11.11, 
11.11, 11.11, 5.56, 16.67, 50, 50), sd = c(NA, 0.6, 0.6, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0, 0)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), groups = structure(list(
    Q9 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("one", "two", "three", "four"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2:3, 4:9, 
        10:11), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: my issue is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241182/how-to-make-geom-text-plot-within-the-canvass-bounds , but the solution isn't solving my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update after clarification: It is not the best solution but it should work for this example. To avoid losing one label because of moving the other to the left, we could stack the labels by **changing both (% and n) nudge_x and nudge_y** and then we can see all of them:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = prop, x = fct_rev(CH), fill = CH, pattern = Q9)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = myColors, name = NULL) +
  geom_label(aes(label = str_glue('{round(prop, 1.5)}%')),
             nudge_y = -2, #15
             nudge_x = 0.05, #0.05
             colour = 'black',
             fill = "yellow",
             label.padding = unit(0.125, "lines"),
             size = 3.5) + 
  
  ### FLIP IT:
  
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  facet_wrap(~Q9, scales = "free_y") +
  
  
  ### SHOW N
  
  geom_label(aes(label= str_glue('n = {n}')),
             size = 2,
             nudge_x = -0.2,
             nudge_y = -2,
             fontface = "italic",
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  
  ### SHOW % IN THE X-AXIS:
  
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100),
                     labels=scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
  
  ### LABELS: 
  
  labs(x = "times",
       y = '%',
       title = "a title") +
  
  ### THEME:
  cowplot::theme_half_open() +
  theme( 
    
    text = element_text(family = "sans",
                        size = 14,
                        hjust = 0.5),
    
    #plot.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0),
    
    
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.justification = "center",
    legend.background = element_rect(color = "black"),  #bloco com legendas
    legend.margin = margin(t = 5, r = 5, b = 3, l = 3),
    
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12), 
    
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                               size = 12), # legenda de baixo
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13.5,
                                face = "bold",
                                margin = margin(t = 20, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13.5,
                                face = "bold"),
    
    ### Facets: 
    
    strip.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",
                                family = "sans",
                                size = 18,
                                colour = 'green'),
    strip.background = element_rect(size = 3,
                                    fill = 'yellow'),
    strip.switch.pad.grid = unit('10', "cm"),
    
    strip.clip = "off")
```

[image]
**First answer:**
This should do what you are after:

To avoid expanding y axis over 100%, we could position the labels in the chart area.

Here we use `prop` in a condition to set y position of the labels:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = prop, x = fct_rev(CH), fill = CH, pattern = Q9)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = myColors, name = NULL) +
  geom_label(aes(label = str_glue('{round(prop, 1.5)}%'), y = ifelse(prop < 10, prop + 5, prop - 5)),
             colour = 'black',
             fill = "yellow",
             label.padding = unit(0.125, "lines"),
             size = 3.5) + 
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  facet_wrap(~Q9, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), labels=scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = "sans", size = 14, hjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.justification = "center",
    # Other theme elements...
  )+
  ### LABELS: 
  
  labs(x = "times",
       y = '%',
       title = "a title") +
  
  ### THEME:
  cowplot::theme_half_open() +
  theme( 
    
    text = element_text(family = "sans",
                        size = 14,
                        hjust = 0.5),
    
    #plot.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0),
    
    
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.justification = "center",
    legend.background = element_rect(color = "black"),  #bloco com legendas
    legend.margin = margin(t = 5, r = 5, b = 3, l = 3),
    
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12), 
    
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                               size = 12), # legenda de baixo
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13.5,
                                face = "bold",
                                margin = margin(t = 20, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13.5,
                                face = "bold"),
    
    ### Facets: 
    
    strip.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",
                                family = "sans",
                                size = 18,
                                colour = 'green'),
    strip.background = element_rect(size = 3,
                                    fill = 'yellow'),
    strip.switch.pad.grid = unit('10', "cm"),
    
    strip.clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @TarJae, thank you, I thought of this, but my y-axis displays proportions, hence it becomes a bit weird to go past 100%

Comment: Please have a look at my update and tell me is this what you are looking for?

Comment: almost there, @TarJae !  the problem is that now it's overlapping with *n* , I'm trying to avoid that, but I'm failing to do so.

Comment: a solution could be to display *n* inside the bars and the % on the right of each bar (I added a picture to the post to illustrated it!)